# Validate input field on key press in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out how I can validate an input field on every key press. If the text in the input field is considered invalid by some validation function, I would like to cancel the keypress or simply restore the original value. This way, the input field should always contain a valid value.

So the input field looks like this:

```
<input [ngModel]="textValue" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)" />
```

In my component, I have declared a textValue property and a function that handles onModelChange:

```
onModelChange(newText: string) {
        if (checkText(newText)) {
            //input is valid, so update the model
            this.textValue = newText;
        }
        else {
            //cancel the keypress or restore the original value
            //HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS?
        }
    }
```

After trying lots of combinations of databinding and handling keypress events, I decided to ask the experts. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I found a solution myself. Instead of handling the ngModelChange, I subscribed to the input event and I use the event.target.value to get/set the appropriate values on every keypress. My input field now looks like this:

```
 <input [value]="textValue" (input)="onInput($event)" />
```

And here the corresponding onInput function:

```
    onInput(event) {
            let newText: string = event.target.value;
            if (checkText(newText)) {
                //input is valid, so update the model
                this.textValue = newText;
            }
            else {
                //restore the original value
                event.target.value = this.textValue;
            }
        }
```

I hope this hels anyone facing the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is ok, but I also find alternative

```
<input ... (keypress)="validateKey($event)" >
```

instead of `keypress` you can use `keydown`, and validation function

```
validateKey(event) {
  let oldval = event.target.value;
  let val = oldval.slice(0,event.target.selectionStart) + event.key + oldval.slice(event.target.selectionEnd);

  // here you have access to input oldval and (current) val

  if(val .... ) return true // allow to push charater
  return false              // not allow to push character
}
```